# Fatal error: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found

Tags: php, ubuntu, internationalization, wamp, amazon-linux

I installed WAMP on my local machine. My PHP version is 5.3.3 in `phpinfo()` but that extension doesn't exist! :(

How can I install this extension without compiling it? [Here](http://pecl.php.net/package/intl) is just source of it.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451468/php-intl-extension

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The extension was there! All you need to do is clearing the comment(;) before this line in `php.ini` file:

#### Windows:

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

#### Linux:

```
;extension=intl
```

to

```
extension=intl
```

Then restart apache2 or php-fpm if you are using it.

If it does not work, then you probably need to change it in the php.ini of the CLI version. First check your version with `php --version` though, so that you change the right php.ini file, it might be different from your php fpm version.

It also might be enough to just install the package e.g. for php 8.2: `sudo apt install php8.2-intl`

Comment: and don't forget to add C:\xampp\php to your system path if you are using XAMPP

Comment: I had the same issue, but even when I uncommented this line - module wasn't loaded properly (no errors in php/apache logs). So please be sure that version of module is correct for the current php version :)

Comment: In my case it was extension=intl

Comment: If it does not work, then you probably need to change it in the php.ini of the CLI version.

Answer (score 37):

if you see this on Debian / other Linux platforms.

`sudo apt-get install php5-intl` - for PHP 5.6

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl` - PHP 7+

Amazon Linux

`sudo yum install php70-intl`

After that restart Apache services.

`sudo service apache2 restart` restart apache to get the changes.

Comment: This one is the right answer on **Ubuntu/Debian** environments, not the one already marked as correct answer. Please go with this method to next problems.

Comment: but the question was asked for WAMP :)

Comment: in amazon linux is actually: sudo yum install php70-intl

Answer (score 5):

in **wamp** or **xampp** open `php.ini` file and find the below line, then remove comment (`;`) at first of it:

`;extension=php_intl.dll`

if you did **not find** the line, add it in the `php.ini` file:

`extension=php_intl.dll`

Answer (score 4):

It may be because of Apache. Restart Apache by following command

```
service httpd restart
```

and try again.

Answer (score 1):

If you added `extension=php_intl.dll` in your `php.ini` and it didn't work you can copy `icu****.dll` files (about five of them) from PHP folder to Apache `/bin` folder then restart Apache and try again.

Answer (score 1):

The following command works like a charm:

```
sudo apt install php8.2-intl
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a software package for deployment on systems you don't manage, there is an alternative to editing php.ini.  You can use the [Symfony version of `IntlDateFormatter`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.4/src/Symfony/Component/Intl/DateFormatter/IntlDateFormatter.php).  With some editing, this can be modified to run in your application.

Note:  this solution only makes sense if you cannot edit php.ini (and if necessary copy the ICU files into Apache).  Otherwise, the "with some editing" portion of this makes the whole thing more complicated than just enabling intl.  Putting this answer here, as this is the earliest question asking about the relevant error.

People who find this useful should upvote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64213125/6660678) to [How to use `IntlDateFormatter` in Symfony?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64213125/6660678).  That provided an important missing step.