# How to get the month name in French and year from a number

Tags: php, date, timestamp

Is there a way in PHP to print the month name and year in french when we have a number in this format `52013` or `42013` ?

---

I have tried:

```
$month = 42013;
$monthNr = substr($month, -5, 1);
$timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNr, 1);
$monthName = date('M', $timestamp );
echo $monthName;
```

but the result is Apr

I'd like to get `Avril` `2013`

Comment: I think you're willing to get "Avril 2013" , not Février...

Comment: possible duplicate of [change month name to french](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309960/change-month-name-to-french)

Comment: Bartdude yeah sorry for the error.. x)

Comment: and cfr My Head Hurts' remark...

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like a simple array of your month names

```
$months = array(1 => 'Janvier', 2 => 'Février'...);
```

Then just look up the month value

```
$monthName = $months[date('n', $timestamp )];
```

Or based on comments suggestion (this is based on the answer in the linked question)

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');

echo strftime('%B', $timestamp);
```