# I18n how to use with date()?

Tags: php, kohana-3

How to sue i18n in kohana 3 with date()?

```
echo date('l jS F Y h:i:s A');
```

I don't know how I can translate day names, month names, etc...

Comment: What about locale? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309960/change-month-name-to-french

Comment: That's so easy, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You should use [strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) function, together with [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php), date function does not support localization strings.

In your example, considering you want the date in french, it may be:

```
<?php

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR');

echo strftime("%A %d %B %G %I:%M:%S %p") . "\n";
```

It will output *Mardi 19 novembre 2013 01:41:59 am*