# Fatal error: Class 'IntlDateFormatter' on Windows

Tags: php, datetime, zend-framework2, phpunit, intl

I have a zf2 application running on my WAMP server.
And i have PHPUnit 4.0.18 by Sebastian Bergmann running too.

My problem is :

```
        echo $this->dateFormat(
               $MyVariable->getDateInvoice(),
                \IntlDateFormatter::LONG, // date
                \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, // time
                $this->navigation()->getTranslator()->getLocale()
            );
```

Works in browser, depends on locale. Works perfectly. Means that IntlDateFormatter class is found right ?

But, when i run PhpUnit from line commande with

```
phpunit
```

i got this error and sure, my build is failing :

```
 Fatal error:  Class 'IntlDateFormatter' not found in ...(myproject path)
```

Why PHPunit can't find this class and how fix this ?

PS : my intl extension on wamp (php.ini) is enabled
this is my configuration of intl module from phpinfo()

```
Internationalization support    enabled
version 1.1.0
ICU version 49.1.2
ICU Data version    49.1.2
```

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242378/fatal-error-class-intldateformatter-not-found

Comment: i just edit my post for say that's not that :) thx anyway

Comment: The php.ini for CLI may differ from the apache one.

Comment: @gontrollez, can you answer that ? php.ini in php dir hasn't intl extension enabled and this is the one wich works for CLI. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check that the php.ini file used in CLI has the extension enabled.