# How to use `IntlDateFormatter` in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-4.4

How can I implement `IntlDateFormatter` in Symfony 4.4.

With reference to https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html I have installed `symfony/intl`

Now when I use it in my code:

```
use Symfony\Component\Intl\DateFormatter\IntlDateFormatter;

    $formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
        "de-DE",
        IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
        IntlDateFormatter::NONE,
        "Europe/Berlin",
        IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
        "MMMM YYYY"
    );
```

I am getting `Cannot instantiate abstract class Symfony\Component\Intl\DateFormatter\IntlDateFormatter`. I know abstract class can not be instantiate. But I am not sure how to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html):

> Composer automatically exposes these classes in the global namespace

This is easier to understand if we check the source code. The class defined at `DateFormatter/IntlDateFormatter.php` is marked as abstract, but there's one implementation at `Resources/stubs/IntlDateFormatter.php` that looks like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\Intl\DateFormatter\IntlDateFormatter as BaseIntlDateFormatter;

/**
 * Stub implementation for the IntlDateFormatter class of the intl extension.
 *
 * @author Bernhard Schussek <bschussek@gmail.com>
 *
 * @see BaseIntlDateFormatter
 */
class IntlDateFormatter extends BaseIntlDateFormatter
{
}
```

In short, the class is a drop-in replacement for builin [IntlDateFormatter](https://php.net/IntlDateFormatter) in the **root namespace**:

```
$fmt = new \IntlDateFormatter(...);
           ^
```

If you don't have the extension installed, auto-loading will load Symfony's implementation automatically.