# ZF2 form HTML5 Number element is not working

Tags: html, zend-framework2, element, zend-form

This is my form

```
<?php
namespace Home\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class CheckPriceForm extends Form
{

    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'distance',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Number',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Distance',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'weight',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Number',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Weight',
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'type' => 'Submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Check Price',                
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

It is give following error

```
/home/dinuka/workspace/free_courier/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/I18n/Validator/Float.php:49

Zend\I18n\Validator component requires the intl PHP extension
```

When i replace Email for Number it is working. Please help me.

Comment: Try adding the Required Intl extension, Few HTML 5 based elements/validations are not fully supported till they are configured, and few dont work on all browsers

Comment: surely you can just google the message? it's pretty self explanitory. http://php.net/manual/en/intl.setup.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

intl extension is missing on your server. so you need to install it.

If you are using Linux try using the following commands

**sudo apt-get install php5-intl**

You then need to restart Apache

**sudo service apache2 restart**

For Windows

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1451770/1508276