# WAMP PHP Startup Error: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, wamp

My WAMP server was working absolutely fine yesterday.  Today I had to restart my computer and something fouled up the works.  The server never fully starts... the task bar icon stays orange.  My projects will open, but only the HTML load and not the PHP.  Here is my error log from PHP...

```
[04-Oct-2014 01:36:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:36:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:36:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_smtp.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:36:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:36:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:36:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_smtp.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:37:28 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:37:28 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:37:28 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_smtp.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:37:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:37:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:37:29 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_smtp.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:38:42 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:38:42 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:38:42 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_smtp.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:38:43 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:38:43 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:38:43 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_smtp.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:44:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:44:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:44:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_smtp.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:44:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:44:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_ldap.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

[04-Oct-2014 01:44:48 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'W:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_smtp.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

 in Unknown on line 0
```

All of the librarys' files are still present in the correct folder.  Anyone know what could cause this?

Update:  Not sure why I have so many different versions, but here they are:
[image: visual c++ redistributable versions]

Update: I did a full reinstall of wamp and I am still getting these errors.

Comment: `%1 is not a valid Win32 application.` are you sure those are 32 bits libraries? or you do not have correct version of Visual C++ Redistributable installed. Check dependencies with http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: I've updated my question to include a screenshot of the installed versions.

Comment: Run the program by the link - it will show you which additional dlls are required or missing. + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138611/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-c-wamp-bin-php-php5-5-12-ext-php-ldap-dll-th + http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,112211

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not involve programing. Please ask at superuser.com

Answer (score 19):

This is just a hiccup in the 2.5 installation process.

All you need to do is this:-

Using the wampmanager (the W icon in the system tray ) do

```
left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Version -> (and click on the version number)
```

This will cause wampmanager to rebuild all the SYMLINKS in the apache/bin folder, and restart Apache. This should fix the issue and stop the errors from appearing in the `php error log`.

Comment: Adding to this, if you installed a new .DLL(addon) and getting this error and cannot resolve this problem then be sure that the installed .DLL requirements are met. (In my case it was the OS)

Answer (score 3):

It's a version mismatch or a missing dependency of these extension dll's.

You might need to install Visual C++ Redistributable:

The PHP VC9 builds (5.4) require you to have the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 x86 or x64 installed.

The VC11 builds (5.5, 5.6) require to have the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 x86 or x64 installed.

php_ldap might need libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll, too... but these file are part of the PHP distribution. This would only be a problem, if they were deleted or if the PHP folder is not on your ENV PATH var.

Try with a fresh PHP download:

- http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.5.17-Win32-VC11-x86.zip
- http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.5.17-Win32-VC11-x64.zip
- http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.5.17-nts-Win32-VC11-x86.zip
- http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-5.5.17-nts-Win32-VC11-x64.zip

Comment: So I downloaded the PHP files, copied them to the correct folder and attempted to restart the server, but still no change.

Comment: Have you appended the PHP folder to the system PATH var?

Comment: Never put any Apache/PHP/MYSQL folders in the Windows PATH when using WAMPServer.

Comment: Why?  It's a common practice to add the PATHs to the binaries to the Windows Path. What does WampServer do differently here?

Comment: Ah, had the same question before and found your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26199341/1163786 Sorry, to say so but the WampServer approach is non standard - even with a PHP version switcher you would append the PATH var...

Comment: But as it is totally unnecesary so we dont do it. It was only ever necessary if you were unable to properly configure your Apache or you followed one of the other incorrect suggestion on the web, of which there are MANY. The PHP and/or Apache version switcher copies (as of WAMPServer3, recreated the symlinks) the correct files into the correct `apache/bin` folder for the active or newly selected version of PHP

Comment: You qualify this as unnecessary and incorrect, but it isn't. Adding executables to the env path is just another way of doing it. On a version switch you have to update the symlinks, where i simply switch the folders. Symlinking is always problematic because of the permission level required. Because only from Win10 (14972) symlinks can be created with `mklink` or via WinAPI `SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_ALLOW_UNPRIVILEGED_CREATE` without needing to elevate the console as administrator. I wish you good luck in maintaining this approach for Vista and 8.

Answer (score 0):

This can be corrected by using the `Wamp` Menus.

Check the apache version that you have.It might be `2.4.9`.

It will cause `WAMPServer to rebuild of all the SYMLINK's in the apache2.4.9/bin folder and that will put the correct symlinks in there for these 2 extensions.` as says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984913/unable-to-load-dynamic-library-c-wamp-bin-php-php5-5-12-ext-php-intl-dll).

So you would need to edit the `\wamp\script\config.inc.php` and find the variable `$phpDllToCopy` and make changes like

```
$phpDllToCopy = array (
'icudt52.dll', 
'icuin52.dll',
'icuio52.dll',
'icule52.dll',
'iculx52.dll',
'icutest52.dll',
'icutu52.dll',
'icuuc52.dll',
'icudt51.dll', 
'icuin51.dll',
'icuio51.dll',
'icule51.dll',
'iculx51.dll',
'icutest51.dll',
'icutu51.dll',
'icuuc51.dll',
'icudt50.dll', 
'icuin50.dll',
'icuio50.dll',
'icule50.dll',
'iculx50.dll',
'icutest50.dll',
'icutu50.dll',
'icuuc50.dll',
'icudt49.dll',
'icuin49.dll',
'icuio49.dll',
'icule49.dll',
'iculx49.dll',
'icutest49.dll',
'icutu49.dll',
'icuuc49.dll',
'libeay32.dll',
'libsasl.dll', 
'libintl.dll',
'php5isapi.dll',
'php5nsapi.dll',
'ssleay32.dll',
'php5ts.dll',
'fribidi.dll', 
'fdftk.dll',   
'libmcrypt.dll',
'libmhash.dll',
'libmysql.dll',
'libmysqli.dll',
'msql.dll',
'ntwdblib.dll',
'php5activescript.dll',
);
```

Comment: But why would you need to symlink or copy these dependencies? If dependencies are not found, it's more likely a PATH problem. Either the PATH was not appended, so the DLLs are not found, or the lookup order of PATHS is not met, resulting in a DLL and dependency version mismatch. Anyway, the server stack should handle this for the user and not force him into tricky configuration stuff. My opinion is, that it should work out of the box, without a requirement for user interaction, just to get PHP running..

Comment: @JensA.Koch With WAMPServer the PATH is not amended for any reason, as it is possible to have multiple versions of PHP which can be activated and deactivated with a click of a menu. If the PATH were used this would make this feature far more complicated and as PATH references to run Apache/PHP or MYSQL is totally unnecessary WAMPserver does not do it.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me after adding a new PHP version to wamp (7.3.17), Adding the path
wamp\bin\php\Path_of_your_PHP
in Environmental variable PATH solved this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Please uninstall wamp which you had been installed.. Try to install Visual C++ ie, the link is given here http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30679 use this link.

after downloading and installing Visual C++ you can install the Wamp server again.. So that it will work..correctly...

Comment: It is totally unnecessary to install Visual Studio all that is required is the Visual C/C++ runtime libraries, not the complete VS.

Answer (score -2):

RESOLVED !!

I was getting the following errors:

1) PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

2) The program can't start because MSVCP110.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

The error was still there even after installing Visual C++ Redistributable.
I resolved it by copying MSVCP110.dll to Windows\System32 folder.  It is up and running now !

Comment: This is not a solution! The MSVCP... dlls should not be manually copied about. They should be properly installed