# Class 'Locale' not found issue on CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm just downloaded the files from [this link](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/lorenzo/2014/09/28/cakephp_3_0_0-beta2_released), extracted and tried execute but I had this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\cake-3-beta-2\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\I18n\I18n.php on line 229
```

I'm running on localhost with xampp... I had the same issue with beta 1 and 2.

Comment: Install php5-intl would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451468/intl-extension-installing-php-intl-dll

Comment: what php5-intl exactly does?

Comment: ...providing i18n functionality. **http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I faced the same problem today. You need to enable the `intl` PHP extension in your PHP configuration (`.ini`).

**Solution Xampp (Windows)**

1. Open `/xampp/php/php.ini`
2. Change `;extension=php_intl.dll` to  `extension=php_intl.dll` (remove the semicolon)
3. Copy all the `/xamp/php/ic*.dll` files to `/xampp/apache/bin`
4. Restart apache in the Xampp control panel

**Solution [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29226651/744478)** (thanks to Annamalai Somasundaram)

1. Install the php5-intl extension `sudo apt-get install php5-intl`

   1.1. Alternatively use `sudo yum install php5-intl` if you are on CentOS or Fedora.
2. Restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart`

**Solution [Mac/OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30387708/2491049) (homebrew)** (thanks to deizel)

1. Install the php5-intl extension `brew install php56-intl`
2. If you get `No available formula for php56-intl` follow [these](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1701) instructions.
3. Restart apache `sudo apachectl restart`

*Eventually you can run `composer install` to check if it's working.*

Comment: Note that in Centos 7 the user may use the PHP FPM package from recent repositories. So now is something like `yum install rh-php73-php-intl`.

Comment: in PHP 7 `extension=intl`

Answer (score 2):

**Change in php ini file**

**For Older php version**

```
;extension=php_intl.dll to extension=php_intl.dll
```

**For New php versions**

```
  ;extension=intl to extension=intl
```