# CakePHP 3.0 installation: intl extension missing from system

Tags: cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

Using the CakePHP docs, I am trying to install 3.0-beta2 using composer but I got this error:

> `cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system`

However, I know for sure that intl is installed (it shows on phpinfo). I'm using PHP 5.4.33/Apache 2.4.10.1

Comment: Is it the bundled version (PHP compiled with `--enable-intl`) or the PECL one? And what does `extension_loaded('intl')` say (on the CLI)? Also is your CLI using the same PHP version/configuration as Apache?

Comment: Thanks @ndm, you actually gave me a hint for the solution: intl was not enabled in php_cli.ini. Everything is ok now.

Comment: You're welcome. Either one of us should add that as answer so that the question appears resolved.

Comment: @JuanCarlos Could you mark an answer as correct if it worked?

Answer (score 119):

I faced the same problem today. You need to enable the **intl** PHP extension in your PHP configuration (`.ini`).

**Solution Xampp (Windows)**

1. Open `/xampp/php/php.ini`
2. Change `;extension=php_intl.dll` to  `extension=php_intl.dll` (remove the semicolon)
3. Copy all the `/xampp/php/ic*.dll` files to `/xampp/apache/bin`
4. Restart apache in the Xampp control panel

**Solution [Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29226651/744478)** (thanks to Annamalai Somasundaram)

1. Install the php5-intl extension `sudo apt-get install php5-intl`

   1.1. Alternatively use `sudo yum install php5-intl` if you are on CentOS or Fedora.
2. Restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart`

**Solution [Mac/OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30387708/2491049) (homebrew)** (thanks to deizel)

1. Install the php5-intl extension `brew install php56-intl`
2. If you get `No available formula for php56-intl` follow [these](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1701) instructions.
3. Restart apache `sudo apachectl restart`

*Eventually you can run `composer install` to check if it's working. It will give an error if it's not.*

Comment: In my version of xampp 5.5.0.0 the dll files where already there and i didn't have to copy it

Comment: Its working for me,but one error is coming

 [InvalidArgumentException]
 Project directory Cake3/ is not empty.

Comment: I am facing this in macos. How do I solve this in mac ?

Comment: It's possible that you get the following error by installing the extension with HomeBrew on macOS Sierra: 

"Error: No available formula with the name "php56-intl" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found."

To fix this, type "homebrew/php/php56-intl".

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have installed xampp 5.6.30 and got the same probleme with my cakephp project. I just enable the intl PHP extension. The dll files where already there and i didn't have to copy them.

Comment: On Mac OS, if you get `No available formula`, you can run `brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php`, then run it again.

Comment: it worked thanks for detailing the steps for newBee

Answer (score 14):

I faced the same issue in ubuntu 12.04

Installed: `sudo apt-get install php5-intl`

Restarted the `Apache: sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 8):

When using **MAMP**

**1 Go to terminal**

```
vim ~/.bash_profile

i

export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin:$PATH
```

Change php5.6.2 to the php version you use with MAMP

Hit ESC,
Type `:wq`,
hit Enter

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

which php

**2 Install Mac Ports**

https://www.macports.org/install.php

`sudo port install php5-intl` **OR** `sudo port install php53-intl`

```
cp /opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/intl.so /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/

{take a good look at the folder names that u use the right ones}
```

**3 Add extension**

Now, add the extension to your `php.ini` file:

```
extension=intl.so
```

*Usefull Link:*
https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693

Comment: I followed the **2 Install Mac Ports** installed intl, copied in extensions, added the extension in php.ini. But its not working. I am using Xampp

Comment: This also works for XAMPP 7.4.2 - used port to install php74-intl, then renamed the file to php_intl.so and copied it to: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/

Answer (score 8):

**OS X Homebrew (May 2015):**

The `intl` extension has been removed from the main `php5x` formulas, so you no longer compile with the `--enable-intl` flag.

If you can't find the new package:

```
$ brew install php56-intl
Error: No available formula for php56-intl
```

Follow these instructions: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1701

```
$ brew install php56-intl
==> Installing php56-intl from homebrew/homebrew-php
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, helped me a lot

Comment: For El Capitan this works out of the box. `brew install php56-intl`

Answer (score 3):

The error message clearly states what the problem is. You need the intl extension installed.

Step 1: install PHP intl you comfortable version

> $sudo apt-get install php-intl

step 2:

For XAMPP Server intl extension is already installed, you need to enable this extension to uncomment below the line in your php.ini file. Php.ini file is located at c:\xampp\php\php.ini or where you have installed XAMPP.

Before uncomment:

> ;extension=php_intl.dll   ;extension=php_mbstring.dll

After uncommenting:

> extension=php_intl.dll   extension=php_mbstring.dll

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: activate intl extension in php_cli.ini. Thanks to @ndm for his input.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using latest version Ubuntu 16.04 or later just do

```
sudo apt-get install php-intl
```

Then restart your apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was not actually trying to run cakephp locally, I was just trying to get it to auto update locally using composer (because I am playing with writing plugins that you install with composer).  Since I don't actually even run it locally I could simply ignore requirements by adding the --ignore-platform-reqs flag.

`php composer.phar update --ignore-platform-reqs`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my running php version is 7.1.x on **mac OSX** .
I installed **intl** command using **brew install php71-intl**.
Placing extension=intl.so inside php.ini was no effect at all. Finally i looked for extension installed directory and there i saw intl.so and placed that path **(extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php71-intl/7.1.11_20/intl.so)** to my **php.ini** file and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (xampp PHP 8.0)
Find `;extension=intl` in `/xampp/php/php.ini`
Remove `;` and Restart Apache

Answer (score 0):

MAKE this

In XAMPP, intl extension is included but you have to uncomment extension=php_intl.dll in php.ini and restart the server through the XAMPP Control Panel.
In WAMP, the intl extension is “activated” by default but not working. To make it work you have to go to php folder (by default) C:\wamp\bin\php\php{version}, copy all the files that looks like icu*.dll and paste them into the apache bin directory C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin. Then restart all services and it should be OK.

if you use XAMPP do this
1. turn off XAMPP 
2. Modifed the php.ini is located in c/:xampp/php/php.ini
3. intl extension is included but you have to uncomment extension=php_intl.dll in php.ini and restart the server through the XAMPP Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu terminal:

Please follow the steps:

**Step-1:**

cd ~

**Step -2:** Run the following commands

sudo apt-get install php5-intl

**Step -3:** You then need to restart Apache

sudo service apache2 restart

---

For Windows(XAMPP) :

Find the Php.ini file:

**/xampp/php/php.ini**

Update the php.ini file with remove (;) semi colon like mentioned below:

**;extension=php_intl.dll** to **extension=php_intl.dll**

and save the php.ini file.

After that you need to

**Restart the xampp using xampp control**.

Answer (score 0):

Intl Means :Internationalization extension which enables  programmers to perform UCA-conformant collation and number,currency,date,time formatting in  PHP scripts.

To enable PHP Intl with PECL can be used.

```
pecl install intl
```

On a plain RHEL/CentOS/Fedora, PHP Intl can be install using yum

```
yum install php-intl
```

On Ubuntu, PHP Intl can be install using apt-get

```
 apt-get install php5-intl
```

Restart Apache service for the changes to take effect.

That's it

Answer (score 0):

For those who get `Package not found` error try `sudo apt-get install php7-intl` then run `composer install` in your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in windows
The error was that I had installed several versions of PHP and the Environment Variables were routing to wrong Path of php [see image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzFXS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Mac OS High Sierra and none of these worked for me. But after searching a lot I found one that worked!

This may seem trivial, but in fact about 2 months ago some clever guys made changes in brew repository, so doing just: `brew install php71-intl` will show you error with message that such recipe doesn’t exists.

Fortunately, there is. There is temporary fix in another brew repo, so all you have to do is:

```
brew tap kyslik/homebrew-php
brew install kyslik/php/php71-intl
```

SOURCE: http://blastar.biz/2018/04/14/how-to-enable-php-intl-extension-for-php-7-1-using-xampp-on-macos-high-sierra/

Answer (score 0):

I use **Linux Ubuntu 20**, you can try this:

Check php installed modules:
`php -m | grep intl`

If there are no result(s) from this command, you should just go ahead and install the module:
`sudo apt-get install php7.4-intl`
*you will need to change `*php7.4` to your desired php version.*

you should restart apache when you're done:
`sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

For fedora linux, with nginx and php-fpm, you can install with:

```
$ dnf install php-intl
```

No nginx restart is needed here.