# CakePHP 3.0 install with composer is broken?

Tags: cakephp, installation, composer-php, cakephp-3.0, bootstrapping

I get this error when trying to pull localhost.

`error: Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\sync\vendor\autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\sync\config\bootstrap.php on line 23`

using composer to install from the cakephp site here: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/quickstart.html

Every time I try this is what I get along with some errors in the cmd here:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs>php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist -s dev cakephp/app sync
Installing cakephp/app (dev-master ebdd94ef28cd742b90fc03a5f8cca46c6306ded2)
  - Installing cakephp/app (dev-master master)
    Loading from cache

Created project in sync
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for cakephp/cakephp 3.0.*-dev -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.0.x-dev].
- cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.

Problem 2
- cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/debug_kit 3.0.x-dev requires cakephp/cakephp 3.0.*-dev -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.0.x-dev].
- Installation request for cakephp/debug_kit 3.0.*-dev -> satisfiable by cakephp/debug_kit[3.0.x-dev].
```

Update:

Interesting take. I have now installed the CakePHP 3 beta on 5 machines and not once have I seen this error again. After looking, I found this (tried all solutions they offered didn't work): [CakePHP 3.0 installation: intl extension missing from system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285280/cakephp-3-0-installation-intl-extension-missing-from-system)

**Solution**

I tried:

- Opening /xampp/php/php.ini
- Changing ;extension=php_intl.dll to  extension=php_intl.dll (remove the semicolon)
- Copy all the /xamp/php/ic*.dll files to /xampp/apache/bin
- Restart apache in the Xampp control panel

For some strange reason, after I restarted apache several more times it just started working randomly out of nowhere 30 mins later. Something must have cached or required a hard reset.

But that finally did it.
And it seems that my title was much more accurate for people to find than the other solved one. Hope this helps more people.

Comment: Please do not do an edit like that again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, just **read** the error! It is telling you already what is wrong.

- Problem 1 (...) cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> **the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.**
- Problem 2 - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires ext-intl -> **the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.**

Install the extensions, problem solved. The [official documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#requirements) tells you also what is *required* to run the framework.

Whenever you get an error, **read it** and pay attention to what it says. It seems to be a common problem that people ignore them these days.

The [installation instructions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html) in the official documentation explain this as well including instructions for XAMPP and WAMP users:

> In both XAMPP and WAMP, mcrypt and mbstring extensions are working by
>   default. In XAMPP, intl extension is included but you have to
>   uncomment extension=php_intl.dll in php.ini and restart the server
>   through the XAMPP Control Panel. In WAMP, the intl extension is
>   “activated” by default but not working. To make it work you have to go
>   to php folder (by default) C:\wamp\bin\php\php{version}, copy all the
>   files that looks like icu*.dll and paste them into the apache bin
>   directory C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin. Then restart all
>   services and it should be OK.

Comment: Interesting take. I have now installed 3 beta on 5 machines and not once have I seen this error. Thank you for your input. After looking, I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285280/cakephp-3-0-installation-intl-extension-missing-from-system