# CakePHP Installation on MAC

Tags: macos, cakephp, terminal, mamp

I am new with MacOS. I have installed MAMP successfully & trying to install CakePHP via terminal in which getting following errors:

> - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - cakephp/cakephp 3.1.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.9 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.8 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.7 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.6 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.5 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.4 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-beta3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-beta2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-beta1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-alpha2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-alpha1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-RC2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0-RC1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - cakephp/cakephp 3.0.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
>         - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp ~3.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.0.0, 3.0.0-RC1, 3.0.0-RC2, 3.0.0-alpha1,
>     3.0.0-alpha2, 3.0.0-beta1, 3.0.0-beta2, 3.0.0-beta3, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.0.6, 3.0.7, 3.0.8, 3.0.9, 3.1.x-dev, 3.0.x-dev].

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP 3.0 installation: intl extension missing from system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285280/cakephp-3-0-installation-intl-extension-missing-from-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is reporting that the "intl" extension is not enabled or installed on your web server.

It has few steps to fix it on MAMP. [Here](http://pagegwood.com/web-development/how-to-enable-intl-extension-mamp-osx-10-9-2/) is explained how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

we can use docker instead off mamp or install apache and php.

Specify your project folder as volume of the docker container.

I'm using : docker-apache-php
https://github.com/romeOz/docker-apache-php

i'm using an external DB, but we can build a new docker image with this image to add mysql

Answer (score 0):

The best way is Docker.

Create the file  docker-compose.yml inside your application with this:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  php-fpm:
    image: webdevops/php-nginx:7.4
    container_name: myapp-webserver
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    environment:
      - WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/app/webroot
    ports:
      - "80:80"

mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    container_name: myapp-mysql
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - ./tmp/data/mysql_db:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - mysql.env
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --init-connect='SET NAMES UTF8;'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Create the file mysql.env

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_DATABASE=my_app
MYSQL_USER=my_user
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
```

Execute docker-compose up to start the services and access the app at http://localhost.

The next thing you need to do is update your database configuration with the correct credentials - the host is the service name, in our case it is “mysql”:

```
'host' => ‘mysql’,
'username' => 'my_user',
'password' => ‘password’,
'database' => 'my_app'
```

Now you can execute

```
docker-compose exec php-fpm bin/cake
```

Comment: This is an impressive improvement to your original answer. Thank you.