# php_intl extension installation error in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, intl

I am using cakephp 3.0.8 on xampp 5.6.8-0 in Mac OS X Yosemite. I have set the database string in the app file and also make the DB for cakephp. I have also uncomment the `extension=php_intl.dll` in `php.ini` file.

but if I try to use phpinfo, it is not showing `php_intl`. And when I try to use cakephp on  localhost it says

> Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cakephp/config/bootstrap.php on line 38

Could anyone tell me please whats the problem.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after uncommenting the line in php.ini?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP 3.0 installation: intl extension missing from system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285280/cakephp-3-0-installation-intl-extension-missing-from-system)

Comment: @Oldskool, yes I have restart the apache but Its not working.
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @ndm, maybe its missing but what is the solution for that ? and thanks for the reply.

Comment: Well, any of those mentioned in the linked question maybe? And how about just googling for `OSX intl`? You'll find more than enough how to explanations by that. On a side note, `.dll` files are for Windows, so whatever you have there is probably not ment to be used with OSX. ps, why did you rollback the edit?

Comment: Sorry for the rollback, that was by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your Linux VPS or Dev Box, the package is missing!!

just run this at command line

sudo apt-get install php5-intl

Why php5? Well it's what I have installed, so if you're running greater than that in the future, just adjust php5 to phpx whatever you're running there!