# CakePHP 3.1.1 Install Error

Tags: php, xampp, cakephp-3.0

I installed Composer for windows file.exe and tried to install cakePHP 3.1.1 just now for the first time, but got the below error. Files[CakePHP311] created in that folder and also have XAMPP[PHP version 5.6.8] + Windows 10 Pro.

What is this error and cakePHP files needed re-setup?

```
User@cccc/C/xampp/htdocs/cakePHP_Blog
$ composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app cakePHPblog
Installing cakephp/app (3.1.1)
  - Installing cakephp/app (3.1.1)
    Downloading: 100%

Created project in cakePHPblog
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Problem

```
- cakephp/cakephp 3.1.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extensi on intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.1.0-beta2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP exten sion intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.1.0-beta requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extens ion intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.1.0-RC1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extensi on intl is missing from your system.
- cakephp/cakephp 3.1.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension i ntl is missing from your system.
- Installation request for cakephp/cakephp ~3.1 -> satisfiable by cakephp/ca kephp[3.1.0, 3.1.0-RC1, 3.1.0-beta, 3.1.0-beta2, 3.1.x-dev].
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP 3.0 installation: intl extension missing from system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285280/cakephp-3-0-installation-intl-extension-missing-from-system)

Answer (score 2):

This error occurred from **php-intl** plugin missing.

If you use Linux, you can try **apt-get install php5-intl** or **yum install php-intl** command.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the extension php_intl is installed and enabled. It comes bundled with the XAMPP installation but may not be enabled. You can enable it by checking for the following line in your php.ini (located at `/xampp/php/php.ini`) which may be commented out and removing the comment:

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

TO (remove the semicolon)

```
 extension=php_intl.dll
```

You will then need to restart Apache from the Xampp Control Panel.

Comment: well to install cakePHP apache/mysql should have been running?

Comment: also reinstall cakePHP after fix or does not influenced?