# Intl extension not getting loaded

Tags: php

I have installed the `intl.so` extension following the instructions on this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285280/cakephp-3-0-installation-intl-extension-missing-from-system/30025651#30025651)**. But its not getting loaded.
When i run `php -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions());";` command in terminal i got

```
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => date
    [2] => ereg
    [3] => libxml
    [4] => openssl
    [5] => pcre
    [6] => sqlite3
    [7] => zlib
    [8] => bcmath
    [9] => bz2
    [10] => calendar
    [11] => ctype
    [12] => curl
    [13] => dba
    [14] => dom
    [15] => hash
    [16] => fileinfo
    [17] => filter
    [18] => ftp
    [19] => gd
    [20] => gettext
    [21] => SPL
    [22] => iconv
    [23] => json
    [24] => ldap
    [25] => mbstring
    [26] => session
    [27] => standard
    [28] => mysqlnd
    [29] => odbc
    [30] => pcntl
    [31] => mysqli
    [32] => PDO
    [33] => pdo_mysql
    [34] => PDO_ODBC
    [35] => pdo_sqlite
    [36] => Phar
    [37] => posix
    [38] => readline
    [39] => Reflection
    [40] => mysql
    [41] => shmop
    [42] => SimpleXML
    [43] => soap
    [44] => sockets
    [45] => exif
    [46] => sysvmsg
    [47] => sysvsem
    [48] => sysvshm
    [49] => tokenizer
    [50] => wddx
    [51] => xml
    [52] => xmlreader
    [53] => xmlrpc
    [54] => xmlwriter
    [55] => xsl
    [56] => zip
    [57] => intl
    [58] => phalcon
    [59] => mhash
)
```

The 57th is `intl`
But when i print this in my project

```
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
die;
```

I got the following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => date
    [2] => ereg
    [3] => libxml
    [4] => openssl
    [5] => pcre
    [6] => sqlite3
    [7] => zlib
    [8] => bcmath
    [9] => bz2
    [10] => calendar
    [11] => ctype
    [12] => curl
    [13] => dba
    [14] => dom
    [15] => hash
    [16] => fileinfo
    [17] => filter
    [18] => ftp
    [19] => gd
    [20] => gettext
    [21] => SPL
    [22] => iconv
    [23] => session
    [24] => json
    [25] => ldap
    [26] => mbstring
    [27] => mcrypt
    [28] => standard
    [29] => mysqlnd
    [30] => mysqli
    [31] => mysql
    [32] => PDO
    [33] => pdo_mysql
    [34] => pdo_pgsql
    [35] => pdo_sqlite
    [36] => Phar
    [37] => posix
    [38] => Reflection
    [39] => imap
    [40] => shmop
    [41] => SimpleXML
    [42] => soap
    [43] => sockets
    [44] => exif
    [45] => sybase_ct
    [46] => sysvsem
    [47] => sysvshm
    [48] => tokenizer
    [49] => wddx
    [50] => xml
    [51] => xmlreader
    [52] => xmlrpc
    [53] => xmlwriter
    [54] => xsl
    [55] => zip
    [56] => apache2handler
    [57] => phalcon
    [58] => mhash
)
```

`intl` is missing here

What do to. What i am missing.

I did this in `php.ini`

```
extension="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/intl.so"
```

and

```
extension="intl.so"
```

and restarted the servers both time.

Comment: did you checked if you have mentioned PHP lib path in Environmental vairables. Maybe this could help https://szemian.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/compiling-intl-extension-for-mamp/

Comment: Did you receive both extension output from terminal? Or is it one from web and one from terminal? php can be configured to use two different php.ini for web and command line

Comment: @PradeepSanjaya First one is from terminal and second one is from web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Find loaded configuration for terminal**

Run following command and find the loaded configuration file. Then add extension line to that configuration file.

```
$ php --ini
```

**Sample output**

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini
```

Add Extension to configuration file

```
extension="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/intl.so"
```

**Find loaded configuration for web**

If you do not know the php.ini loaded from your web server.

Add following code to a php file and visit to that url. You can find the Loaded configuration file in output. Add Extension to that configuration file and restart webserver.

//info.php

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Comment: i got two files there `"php.ini-development"` and `"php.ini-production"`. Which one to edit

Comment: What is the loaded configuration file? If you do not see any file in front of "Loaded Configuration File" php configuration and if it is your development server, you can just rename php.ini-development to php.ini and add your extension to that file.