# CakePHP 3 extension=php_intl.dll

Tags: php, macos, cakephp-3.0, intl

I am trying to push my CakePHP to my Mac

I called phpinfo to see where my php.ini lies - open it and uncommented the extension - usually that did the trick, but it still throws the error and in the phpinfo() it never showed. Any idea?

Comment: Did you restart your web server (Apache?) after updating php.ini?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP 3.0 installation: intl extension missing from system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285280/cakephp-3-0-installation-intl-extension-missing-from-system)

Comment: PHP on OSX doesn't use `.dll` files, but `.so` ones, so you seem to be doing something wrong. Please add more details about your environment, otherwise this question is a duplicate.

Comment: This fixed it !

http://mrgott.com/misc/11-update-modify-system-integrity-protection-in-el-capitan-to-install-mcrypt-and-intl-php-extensions

Greetz to MrGott - Nice Job!