# Am trying to download cakephp and getting missing extension message

Tags: cakephp

Am trying to download cakephp using the following code frome the terminal - php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app bookmarker
but it tells me am missing some extensions in my system -
  Problem 1
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.2.x-dev requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.2.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.2.0-RC1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.

Any suggestions please.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.2.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp ~3.2 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.2.0, 3.2.0-RC1, 3.2.1, 3.2.x-dev].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP 3.0 installation: intl extension missing from system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285280/cakephp-3-0-installation-intl-extension-missing-from-system)

Comment: Thanks Salines,  say that was the case, how do I go about resolving that. Bear in mind I use apache pre installed in mac.

Comment: I'm not use Mac, but you need to uncomment intl extension in your php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable intl extension from php.ini 
if you use xampp  [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451468/intl-extension-installing-php-intl-dll)

Otherwise find **php.ini**

search **intl.dll**

remove semiclone infront of it  **(for xampp)**

remove  #  **(for wampp)**

Save it and restart server

After this process try to download again

Comment: Thanks Rana, but I use the apache that comes pre installed with mac's OX. Does the same solution still applies.

Comment: Actually I'm not familiar with mac. :(

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem while installing CakePHP for a new project. What I did was the following:

1) Upgrade the PHP to 5.6 (http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-php-on-osx) and check my `phpinfo()` file for `intl` to be enabled. As it was enabled I thought that the default Mac OS PHP in use was not the one I was checking in `phpinfo()`. Indeed when prompting on the terminal `php -v` or `which php` I realised the CLI was using PHP 5.5.3 so I modified my `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile`...

2)`vim ~/.profile`

`#export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`

`PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH`

3) `source ~/.profile`

4) `vim ~/.bash_profile`

`#export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`

`export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH`

5) Close and reopen the terminal.

6) Check again `php -v` or `which php` and PHP 5.6 appeared.

7) Run again `php composer.phar create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app app_name` and the error was gone.

It turns out that some months ago I had installed homebrew and with it another PHP version got installed as the default Mac OS PHP with no `intl` enabled.