# CakePHP3 - Apache/Server Error 500 - MAMP

Tags: mamp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to set up a new CakePHP3 project using MAMP to host it locally.

When I install using composer I'm getting this error but the application still creates:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.



 Problem 1
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.2.5 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.2.4 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.2.3 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.2.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.2.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - cakephp/cakephp 3.2.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp ~3.2 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 3.2.4, 3.2.5].
```

Is this my issue?

I've followed all the steps here with no avail: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#url-rewriting

I've set my Document Root to appname/webroot

The error in the browser I'm getting is:

```
The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
500
```

What can I try?

Comment: you need to enable the intl extension http://stackoverflow.com/a/26308767/4452423

Comment: Okay it's working, obviously I needed to do a fresh install of Cake. Thanks