# I got an error after install cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp

Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in D:\wamp\www\cakephp\config\bootstrap.php on line 23
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0000  136384  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0000  163624  require( 'D:\wamp\www\cakephp\config\bootstrap.php' )   ..\index.php:27
3   0.0000  163784  trigger_error ( )   ..\bootstrap.php:23

Comment: You must enable the intl extension!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP 3.0 installation: intl extension missing from system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285280/cakephp-3-0-installation-intl-extension-missing-from-system)

Comment: Reading and understanding the text is rocket science! Searching for it even more complicated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the configuration file `php.ini`

search for `extension=php_intl.dll`
and remove semicolon from here.
Restart your server and you are done.

Update : According to the cakephp [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#requirements)

> In WAMP, the intl extension is “activated” by default but not working.
>   To make it work you have to go to php folder (by default)
>   C:\wamp\bin\php\php{version}, copy all the files that looks like
>   icu*.dll and paste them into the apache bin directory
>   C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin. Then restart all services and
>   it should be OK.

Comment: i have already remove semicolon from extension=php_intl.dll in php.ini

Comment: @user3801317 Have you restarted your server ?

Comment: Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in D:\wamp\www\cakephp\config\bootstrap.php on line 23