# CakePHP3 http 500 on Webserver

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp-3.0

I have finished my first CakePHP3 app and want to upload it to my Webserver.

The app should run on a subdomain (test.domain.com) which go to the folder `/test/`

In "test" I uploaded my application. When I open test.domain.com I get everytime

> HTTP ERROR 500

I don't know what I should change. I also try to upload the Cake3 skeleton App and get the same Error.

My .htaccess in my app folder (/test)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule    ^$    /test/webroot/    [L]
 RewriteRule    (.*) test/webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

And my .htaccess in the webroot folder (/test/webroot/)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /test/webroot/
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also try modified .htaccess with:

```
.../webroot/
and
.../
```

What should I change?

**UPDATE 1**

In the error log I get this error:

> 19.08.2016 21:16:55 test.domain.com [client 79.244.43.0] PHP Fatal error:  You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in /mnt/web011/b3/01/54124301/htdocs/test/config/bootstrap.php on line 23

Comment: Do you have any error logs?

Comment: no I only get the 500 error. The log folder in Cake is empty

Comment: It is Internal server error what web server are you using?

Comment: look inside `/var/logs/apache2/error.log`. Check if there's any errors there.

Comment: added Error.log in Update 1

Comment: In php's httpd config file enable intl.dll. By default it is not enable.

Comment: Maybe this question helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/26285280/1741542

Comment: I don't have access to the php config file, I just can set PHP version. I contact my provider and wait now for a answer. Any other way to fix it without php. ini  or config?