# Symfony2, getting error on running composer update

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, payum

Composer.json

```
{
"name": "go-get-me",
"license": "proprietary",
"type": "project",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "sylius/flow-bundle": "^0.15.0",
    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "^0.4.1",
    "stripe/stripe-php": "^3.14",
    "misd/phone-number-bundle": "^1.1",
    "twig/extensions": "^1.3",
    "php-http/guzzle6-adapter": "^1",
    "payum/payum-bundle": "^2.1@dev",
    "payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "^1.3.3",
    "pimax/fb-messenger-php": "dev-master",
    "twilio/sdk": "^4.10",
    "vresh/twilio-bundle": "^1.0",
    "infusionsoft/php-sdk": "^1.2",
    "hayageek/oauth2-yahoo": "^2.0",
    "glifery/entity-hidden-type-bundle": "^1.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.3",
    "faisalman/simple-excel-php" : "0.3.*"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin",
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.5.9"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    }
}
```

}

[image: Error Message]

I am a newbie in symfony2. Here I am updating the required dependencies, Its shows an error, I am confused, do I need to take the clone of payum bundle or not? if yes then what must be the path? As My current path is /e/xampp/htdocs/nitu.dhaka/2016/subscription.

Comment: You have some conflicts in your packages versions, please post your composer.json + post your errors in text format instead of image please.

Comment: @olibiaz: yes, give me 2 mins

Comment: The errors are self explanatory, you just have to install the right version and all packages it depends on.

Comment: @ElSam : I have mentioned  required pacakages in composer.json? Still not installing and thrown this error. Is there any other way to install dependent packages

Answer (score 2):

**1/** Your problem one is that you required development a version of your libraries.

```
"payum/payum-bundle": "^2.1@dev",
```

You can lower your `minimum-stability` to dev, but you can have some unexpected behaviour since you will potentially accept to install some unstable versions of all packages. If you want still process add this line to your composer.json

```
"minimum-stability": "stable",
```

Please refer to https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more information.

However, my advice is to use a non dev version of your packages, for example:

```
"payum/payum-bundle": "^2.1@dev",
```

could become

```
"payum/payum-bundle": "~2.1",
```

**2/** A library of php is missing for some of your packages `requires ext-intl *`. In order to install it, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26308767/2377164

Answer (score 0):

Ohh Finally Installation started, Following changed I have done:- 
1. Configured ext-intl package by uncomment it from php.ini, that is in xampp/php/
2.And very important replace 
payum/payum-bundle": "^2.1@dev", to "payum/payum-bundle": "^2.0",
        "payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "^1.3",
I thing there is a combination for 
"payum/payum-bundle": "^2.0",
"payum/paypal-express-checkout-nvp": "^1.3",

This worked for me.

Thanks.