# intl extension error when using XAMPP on Mac

Tags: macos, xampp, cakephp-3.0

I want to run my installation of CakePHP 3 with XAMPP 7 on my Mac and always get the following error message in my browser:

> Fatal error: You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cake_test/config/bootstrap.php
>   on line 27

I already did the following:

- I commented out `extension=php_intl.dll` in the XAMPP’s php.ini file.
- I installed `intl` with the terminal command `sudo pecl install intl`
- When my PHP path is set for “/usr/bin/php” I get “intl” when I enter the command `root$: php -m | grep intl`. That means it is successfully installed.
- After I've switched my path to `/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php` I get PHP warnings:

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_intl.dll'
>   - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_intl.dll,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0 Warning: PHP Startup: Unable
>   to load dynamic library
>   '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_intl.dll'
>   - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/php_intl.dll,
>   9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

I would need `intl` for XAMPP and not for the pre-installed Apache on my Mac, but I don’t know how to get it. Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Did you restart the web server after updating php.ini?

Comment: `.dll` files are for Windows...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP 3.0 installation: intl extension missing from system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285280/cakephp-3-0-installation-intl-extension-missing-from-system)

Comment: @GregSchmidt Yes, I restarted the Apache in XAMPP Application Manager. I even restarted with the Terminal command `sudo apachectl restart`.
@ndm No, it's actually not a duplicate from your suggested discussion.

It confuses me that I only find solutions to install `intl` for the path `/usr/local/bin/php` (Terminal: `which php`) and when I switch to the path '/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php' I get the errors.
I really don't know how to use CakePHP 3 with XAMPP on my Mac without having the fatal error to enable intl extension.

Comment: I finally managed it with that description: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886117/php-intl-installation-on-xampp
In php.ini on my Mac-XAMPP, I was adding the .DLL instead of "extension=intl.so".