# Cakephp : intl extension missing

Tags: cakephp-3.7

I am trying to install CakePHP 3.8 in my mac ( macos high sierra version 10.13.6), but i had this problem since yesterday tell me that extension intl is missing from your system

```
 User-iMac:TEST zakaria$ composer create-project --prefer-dist 
 cakephp/app my_app_name
 Installing cakephp/app (3.8.0)
 - Installing cakephp/app (3.8.0): Loading from cache
 Created project in my_app_name
 Loading composer repositories with package information
 Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of 
 packages.

 Problem 1
 - cakephp/cakephp 3.8.1 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP 
 extension intl is missing from your system.
 - cakephp/cakephp 3.8.0 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP 
 extension intl is missing from your system.
 - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp 3.8.* -> satisfiable 
by 
cakephp/cakephp[3.8.0, 3.8.1].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini 
files:
 - /etc/php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files 
are 
used by PHP in CLI mode.
User-iMac:TEST User$
```

- i tried to uncomment extension=php_intl.dll in php.ini
- i tried to add extension=intl.so

And so many solutions out there but nothing seems to work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP 3.0 installation: intl extension missing from system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285280/cakephp-3-0-installation-intl-extension-missing-from-system)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Intl extension is missing on native instalation of PHP 7.1.24 on Mac OS high sierra.

Download PHP 7.1 from php.net, install XCode Command Line Tools, ICU (http://site.icu-project.org/), Autoconf, reinstall the developer tools header files, and finally install Intl extension using phpize.

Important: you'll have to disable SIP.