# Using php locale class in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, locale

I am trying to get full country name from country code, i.e. US to United States

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Classes\ImportexportDomains;
use App\Accounts;
use App\Settings;
use Locale;

class SyncCalls extends Command {

protected $name = 'sync:calls';

public function fire() {

 $inbound_originating_address_region_full = Locale::getDisplayRegion('-'.$inbound_originating_address_region, 'en');
}
}
```

On running I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Locale' not found in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/nanohost/app/Console/Commands/SyncCalls.php on line 235


 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
 Class 'Locale' not found
```

Comment: Try with a slash instead of importing it: `\Locale::getDisplayRegion(...`.

Comment: @TheFallen have tried that , same error

Comment: What version of laravel are you using? See https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/facades#facade-class-reference for a list of facades.

Comment: @Johannes im using 5.2 - so is it not possible to use the php class?

Comment: Sorry, I thought Locale was a laravel facade, turns out it's a php feature. Have you tried enabling the php_intl extension? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153837/class-locale-not-found-issue-on-cakephp-3

Comment: @Johannes - Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Open php.ini file in c:\xampp\php folder.
Find ';extension=intl' and remove semi-colon.
Restart Apache.
That's all.