# how to fix: Fatal error: Locale 'en_AU.UTF-8' on my localhost

Tags: php, bootstrapping

Im encountering issues with php development (im new into this language)

I have setup a local copy of the development files for our project. However, when im trying to view it on my localhost it shows me this error

**Fatal error:** Locale 'en_AU.UTF-8' is not available in **C:\xampp\htdocs\[projectname]\bootstrap.php** on line 46

this is the code on bootstrap.php on line 46

```
define('LOCALE',   'en_AU.UTF-8');
define('TIMEZONE', 'Australia/Perth');

    if ( !setlocale(LC_ALL, LOCALE) ) {
  trigger_error("Locale '" . LOCALE . "' is not available", E_USER_ERROR);
}

function __dump_debug() {
  global $composer_loader;
  echo "<!-- DEBUG INFORMATION AT " . date('c') . "\n";
  print_r([
    'APP_ROOT'     => APP_ROOT,
    'PHP_ENV'      => PHP_ENV,
    'TMP_DIR'      => TMP_DIR,
    'LOG_DIR'      => LOG_DIR,
    'LOCALE'       => setlocale(LC_ALL, 0),
    'TIMEZONE'     => date_default_timezone_get(),
    'USER'         => rollbar_get_current_user(),
    'SQL'          => [
      'VARIABLES' => mysqlGetPairs('SHOW SESSION VARIABLES')
    ],
    'INCLUDE_PATH' => get_include_path(),
    'CLASSES'      => get_declared_classes(),
    'COMPOSER'     => [
      'CLASSMAP' => $composer_loader->getClassMap(),
      'PREFIXES' => $composer_loader->getPrefixes(),
    ],
    'INFLECTOR'    => [
      'ACRONYMS' => ICanBoogie\Inflector::get()->inflections->acronyms
    ]
  ]);
  echo "-->";
}
```

how do I fix this error? any inputs will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to enable PHP's [INTL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php).

You should find everything you need for XAMPP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451468/intl-extension-installing-php-intl-dll).