# Magento installation using XAMPP PHP Extension intl

Tags: magento, xampp

Im trying to install magento using XAMPP and im getting the following errors in the attached screen print. Can anybody help?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BaGl.jpg

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451468/intl-extension-installing-php-intl-dll

Answer (score 2):

For removing "PHP Extension intl" error, we have to enable PHP Extension intl , follow the Steps..

```
Open the xampp/php/php.ini file in any editor.
Search ";extension=php_intl.dll"

kindly remove the starting semicolon ( ; )

Like :

;extension=php_intl.dll

to

extension=php_intl.dll

Save the xampp/php/php.ini file.
Restart your xampp/wamp
```

Hope its work..Cheers..

Comment: @SavanDholu , may i know the process you followed? have you restart your xampp/wamp?

Comment: Yes, 
Same process i have follow but again not working. and restart xampp. Check this image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/twA2q.png

Comment: This is not the issue of php_intl.dll. here another dll file missing so you need to add msvcp140.dll file.
https://www.dllme.com/dll/files/msvcp140_dll.html
https://www.dll-files.com/msvcp140.dll.html
https://fix4dll.com/msvcp140_dll

Comment: where is put this ddl file

Comment: Please follow instructions..
https://fix4dll.com/how_to_install_dll_files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137330/discussion-between-amarendra-kumar-and-savan-dholu).

Answer (score 0):

Here is all command lines to install magento2

**PHP Extension xsl and intl.  CMD**

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
sudo apt-get install php5-xsl
sudo php5enmod xsl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**PHP Extension mcrypt.  CMD**

```
sudo updatedb 
locate mcrypt.ini
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score -1):

To enable intl extension replace

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

with

```
extension=/php_intl.dll
```

(simply remove semicolon & then restart your server)