# How to fix PHP Warning: Unable to load dynamic library: php_intl.ddl

Tags: php, macos

How can I fix this issue please? I am running php5.6 on OS X 10.11.3

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_intl.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/php_intl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Please post your code.  You're doing something thats throwing an error, but we cant troubleshoot the error if we don't know what you're doing thats triggering it.

Answer (score 6):

Edit /etc/php.ini and uncomment the line extensions php_intl.dll

Comment: You mean *uncomment*, right?

Comment: @Annabel *commenting* to me means to *add* a comment to the line in question.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - yes you are right *uncomment* the line. (I have removed my original comment)

Answer (score 5):

You may need to edit your php.ini file like so, if your hosting provider allows it:
Change the following line:

```
     ;extension=php_intl.dll
```

to

```
      extension=php_intl.dll
```

But see also:

[intl extension: installing php_intl.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451468/intl-extension-installing-php-intl-dll)

Comment: Thanks! I was on my local server.