# php.ini does not contain extension=php_intl.dll

Tags: php, visual-studio, xampp, iis-express

I'm using php tools for visual studio. The php.ini is located under `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v7.1`
,here is the screen shot of `phpinfo():`

[image: phpinfo()]

I need `PHP - INTL Extension`, but php.ini does not contain `php_intl.dll`
 and `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v7.1` folder contains following files:

- icudt36.dll icuin36.dll icuio36.dll icule36.dll iculx36.dll
  icutu36.dll icuuc36.dll

  `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v7.1\ext` folder contains `php_intl.dll`

> How to install the missing php_intl.dll?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451468/intl-extension-installing-php-intl-dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added `extension=php_intl.dll` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v7.1\php.ini`

**Note:**
`php_intl.dll` is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\PHP\v7.1\ext` folder

Thanks to @Renjith