# TYPO3 install:PHP extension "intl" not load

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x

1.Installing TYPO3 CMS Screenshot

[image: Installing TYPO3 CMS]

2.Ubuntu & PHP Version

[image: Ubuntu & PHP Version]

3.PHP.ini Config

[image: PHP.ini Config]

4.TYPO3 Version

[image: TYPO3 Version]

Comment: Did you restart/reload apache2 after enable extension intl in php.ini?
Did you check phpinfo() output ? https://i.imgur.com/i4pQ9yi.png

Comment: @SteffenMächtel thank you. It’s working fine now when restart apache

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, activating
extension=intl
in your php.ini
and restarting Apache will solve the problem.

In my case, using Windows, this was not sufficient:
Additionally, I had to add the php install directory to my windows path variable!

Details about this can be found here:
[intl extension: installing php_intl.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451468/intl-extension-installing-php-intl-dll/6086991#6086991)